# JSON can't returning cyrillic data

Tags: php, json, mysqli

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456", "json_test");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM names";
$query = mysqli_query( $connect,$sql );
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ){
    $arr[]=array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'title' => $row['name']
    );
}
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

is returning ??????? and it's cyrillic text(utf-8). How to fix it?

Comment: Add `mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");` after your connection and check!!

Comment: That's working fine. Thanks @Saty

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")**. Please check the below code and let me know

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456", "json_test");
$connect->set_charset("utf8");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM names";
$query = mysqli_query( $connect,$sql );
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ){
    $arr[]=array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'title' => $row['name']
    );
}
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

Comment: mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8"); put this line after my connection than it's working. I think your solution is same. Thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 1):

The `mysqli_set_charset()` function specifies the default character set to be used when sending data from and to the database server.

You need to add `mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");` after your connection!

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123456", "json_test");
mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php